# Do Continuing Education Masters offer something to somebody's CV for industry jobs?

Tags: masters

Do Continuing Education Masters offer something to somebody's CV? I mean is it a "plus" for our CV in order to have more possibilities to be accepted in industry? Are they equivalent to University's Masters?

Comment: What is a "Continuing Education Masters"?

Comment: These are Masters degrees, on a field, where you can attend either in campus or online or blended, and are targeted in people who don't have a lot of time to attend, and the deadline to finish the Master degree is extended to 4-5 years. Rather than the usual 1.5 - 2 years that exist in mainstream  Masters degrees.

Comment: So, part time and maybe evening classes?

Comment: Yes, something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of non-research institutions offer these. But I think that *Continuing Education* is just an institutional framework under which they are offered. I doubt that such degrees are labeled specifically "Continuing Education Masters", but just as "Masters".

So, like most degrees the value depends on what is in them and the general reputation of the institution. In some fields there is little difference between a masters done full time during the day and one of these.

So, in a CV, if you got a masters in math from Jiminy Cricket State College, you just list it that way. It will be evaluated when necessary by those who need to do so. For industry it is probably fine.

In some fields, a university's backing might be needed, though probably to support labs and such.

Many masters degrees are just course based, even at research institutions.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing Education Master's programs can  add value to your CV and increase your chances in the industry (even if they differ in "structure" or "format" from traditional university Master's programs). However, their value may vary based on the industry and the employer. Some industries may value practical skills and real-world experience more than the format of the degree.